# Jsoup not showing text

Tags: java, jsoup

So i have been working on this for 2 hours now did some searching about jsoup sounded pretty cool so i got in to it!

Am facing this problem now with trying to get the text of this span:

```
<span class="badge points2">7,800P</span>
```

I tried using this code to get: 7,800P

```
 String points_test = alert_second.select("span[class=badge points2]").text();
```

What am i doing wrong?

Any fix or help is great

Thanks to all who try to help and for those who tried there best!

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup documentation [provide](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) the following example:

```
.class  elements with a class name of "class"
```

So try something like:

```
String points_test = alert_second.select("span.badge.points2").text();
```